# How to run a script multiple times in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to run this script on my page.

```
    <label for="proof1">1st proof pic:</label>
  <input type="file" name="proof1" id="proof1">
  <label for="p1user">Submitted By:</label>
  <select name="p1user" style="width:100px">
  <option value="None"></option>
  <?php while($rows = $users->fetch_array())
        {
                $user = $rows['username'];
                echo "<option value='$user'>$user</option>";
        } ?> </select>
  <br>
  <label for="proof2">2nd proof pic:</label>
  <input type="file" name="proof2" id="proof2">
  <label for="p2user">Submitted By:</label>
  <select name="p2user" style="width:100px">
  <option value="None"></option>
  <?php while($rows = $users->fetch_array())
        {
                $user = $rows['username'];
                echo "<option value='$user'>$user</option>";
        } ?> </select>
  <br>
  <label for="proof3">3rd proof pic:</label>
  <input type="file" name="proof3" id="proof3">
  <label for="p1user">Submitted By:</label>
  <select name="p3user" style="width:100px">
  <option value="None"></option>
  <?php while($rows = $users->fetch_array())
        {
                $user = $rows['username'];
                echo "<option value='$user'>$user</option>";
        } ?> </select>
```

The first time works fine but the other two come back blank. What am I doing wrong?
Yes, `$users` is defined earlier in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to seek back to the beginning of the result set before each fetch loop, with `$users->data_seek(0);`.

```
  <label for="proof1">1st proof pic:</label>
  <input type="file" name="proof1" id="proof1">
  <label for="p1user">Submitted By:</label>
  <select name="p1user" style="width:100px">
  <option value="None"></option>
  <?php while($rows = $users->fetch_array())
        {
                $user = $rows['username'];
                echo "<option value='$user'>$user</option>";
        } ?> </select>
  <br>
  <label for="proof2">2nd proof pic:</label>
  <input type="file" name="proof2" id="proof2">
  <label for="p2user">Submitted By:</label>
  <select name="p2user" style="width:100px">
  <option value="None"></option>
  <?php $users->data_seek(0);
        while($rows = $users->fetch_array())
        {
                $user = $rows['username'];
                echo "<option value='$user'>$user</option>";
        } ?> </select>
  <br>
  <label for="proof3">3rd proof pic:</label>
  <input type="file" name="proof3" id="proof3">
  <label for="p1user">Submitted By:</label>
  <select name="p3user" style="width:100px">
  <option value="None"></option>
  <?php $users->data_seek(0);
        while($rows = $users->fetch_array())
        {
                $user = $rows['username'];
                echo "<option value='$user'>$user</option>";
        } ?> </select>
```

Or you could put all the names in an array and use that each time.

```
$usernames = [];
while ($rows = $users->fetch_assoc()) {
    $usernames[] = $rows['username'];
}
  <label for="proof1">1st proof pic:</label>
  <input type="file" name="proof1" id="proof1">
  <label for="p1user">Submitted By:</label>
  <select name="p1user" style="width:100px">
  <option value="None"></option>
  <?php 
    foreach ($usernames as $user) {
        echo "<option value='$user'>$user</option>";
    } ?> </select>
  <br>
  <label for="proof2">2nd proof pic:</label>
  <input type="file" name="proof2" id="proof2">
  <label for="p2user">Submitted By:</label>
  <select name="p2user" style="width:100px">
  <option value="None"></option>
  <?php 
    foreach ($usernames as $user) {
        echo "<option value='$user'>$user</option>";
    } ?> </select>
  <br>
  <label for="proof3">3rd proof pic:</label>
  <input type="file" name="proof3" id="proof3">
  <label for="p1user">Submitted By:</label>
  <select name="p3user" style="width:100px">
  <option value="None"></option>
  <?php 
    foreach ($usernames as $user) {
        echo "<option value='$user'>$user</option>";
    } ?> </select>
```

Comment: ok, maybe i'm misunderstanding how your answer helps... what you just gave me seems like a different way to do exactly what i'm doing. Maybe context would help a bit? I'm trying to create a dropdown with the names of all users in it. I got that working (the above code) but when i try to run it into three separate drop downs it works the first time but not the other two that i use the exact same code.

Comment: actually i get what you are talking about, making a script loop... that's not what i'm going for here. i need this same code to run in three totally different places on the same php page

Comment: Put `$users->data_seek()` before each loop. Or just put all the usernames into an array and use that.

Comment: i updated the question... maybe that will help. i'm not trying to loop the script.

Comment: Thank you for the fix. i added $users->data_seek(0); to the other two and it worked... sorry i didn't get what you were saying at first